# Issues with loading two excel datasets into R

Tags: r, excel, dataset

I am having some issues with loading two excel datasets into R.
I am getting an error that says

> There is no package called 'xlsx'

How do I fix this?

```
install.packages(xlsx)
library(xlsx)

yourdata <- read.xlsx("EPL.TransferFees.One.xlsx", sheetName="EPL.TransferFees.One")
yourdata <- read.xlsx("EPL.TransferFees.Two.xlsx", sheetName="EPL.TransferFees.Two")
```

Comment: Hello Thomas, 
you should give different names to yourdata
e.g., yourdata1 <- blah
youdata2 <- blah

Answer (score 3):

`install.packages` expects a string :

```
install.packages('xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `require` from `base R` which does the installation of the package if not present

```
require(xlsx)
```